# How to define a metric for the number of lines of code in test package?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm working with SonarQube 6.4 and a java project based on maven. We are using SonarQube a lot and I now want to define a metric regarding tests.

Is there a way to know how many lines of code a team has written in the `test` package?

Answer (score 0):

This is a metric that was considered but was never considered as interesting enough (in regards to other features) to be implemented on the SonarJava plugin. See this ticket for more details : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-79